# Execute puppeteer code within a javascript function

Tags: javascript, electron, puppeteer

Well.., I am new to `puppeteer` and `electron` too.

I have a basic puppeteer code working as below :

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');


(async () => 
{
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });

    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setViewport({ width: 1366, height: 768});

    await page.goto('https://www.google.co.in', {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});

})();
```

That's great. Now i do not wants to open a browser whenever my electron app starts. Rather i want to open it on a particular event and within a javascript function. Which will be called whenever i want. As below :

```
global.RunCommand = function(param)
{
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });

    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setViewport({ width: 1366, height: 768});

    await page.goto('https://www.google.co.in', {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});


    return 'Done : ' + param;
}
```

which throws :

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
                    ^^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
at Module._compile (module.js:606:28)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:653:10)
at Module.load (module.js:561:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:504:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:496:3)
```

Any help will be appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: `pupeeteer` is not an `electron` project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`global.RunCommand` is a [async](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) function, you must always declare the  **async** word in an asynchronous function

```
global.RunCommand = async function(param)
{
 ...
}
```

Comment: Yes it worked but i want to return the string 'done' on_complete; But it returning string 'done' before completing code..!!??

Comment: @sandhyasasane You can use a callback function for that